# How to launch a mainframe application from lean FT

Tags: mainframe, leanft

New process builder concept or terminal emulator. Which one is to be used her

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm not able to understand what you are asking.  Partly because I don't know what a "lean FT" is (maybe a link to what that is or spell it out so I could look it up on the internet).  Also when asking questions, its good to include things you've tried doing.  Have you searched for this answer on the internet and didn't find it?  If so include that in your question.  Stack Overflow (SO) has a good web page that provides suggestions on how to ask questions, so this link might help for your future questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: As your question stands, I don't think it will be answered.  Don't be disheartened, people will answer if if they know what you are asking.  Feel free to edit your question and add more information... Help us to help you.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I believe Ayushi means LeanFT. LeanFT is a functional testing tool that used to be part of HP Enterprise's test tools product set that was sold to Micro Focus in 2017. Micro Focus renamed the product "UFT Developer."

"How to launch a mainframe application" is ambiguous, though. Mainframes are sophisticated, robust, high throughput servers that run a variety of operating systems and practically any/every application you can imagine. I'll attempt an answer, though.

If the application runs on z/OS, z/VSE, z/TPF, or z/VM CMS, if the application only (or predominantly) offers a "3270" terminal-oriented user interface, and if test user access authentication and authorization is permitted, then the application can be launched from Micro Focus UFT Developer via its terminal emulator functionality. Unfortunately this feature only works on UFT Developer for Windows. Documentation is available here:

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uftdev/en/15.0/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/TE_Addin_Overview.htm

This feature also evidently works with the previous version (LeanFT Version 14 for Windows). Please note that a 3270 terminal emulator for Windows will also be required since this UFT Developer feature uses "HLLAPI," an API that IBM introduced many years ago that many 3270 terminal emulators provide. The documentation describes several choices, such as IBM Personal Communications (i.e. the IBM Host Access Client Package). I strongly recommend configuring and using a TLS encrypted TN3270E connection as a basic security precaution.

That's certainly not the only way to "launch a mainframe application" and may not even be applicable, as mentioned above. As another example, z/OS includes the z/OS Management Facility (z/OSMF). z/OSMF provides an authorized jobs interface, a set of REST APIs that can accept job submissions (i.e. launch applications). As yet another example, mainframes run Linux (extremely well), so any/all application launching techniques that work with Linux work with Linux, including on mainframes.

Comment: I am using IBM personal Communications to launch my mainframe application. Can you please tell me how to launch mainframe application using java in lean FT